# Firebase Database onChildChanged not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have written a code which fetches only new data from Firebase database:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("object");
query = mDatabase.orderByChild("time").startAt(++lastRowTime);
```

Now, issue I am facing that whenever old data modified `onChildChanged()` not called as my listener does not include old data.

How can I receive only new data when app starts and `onChildChanged()` called every time whenever old or new data gets changed.

Should I create 2 listeners but I think this will take too many resources.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried to use [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)?

Comment: No, I want to store data in local db. Can I achieve this using FirebaseUI?

Comment: No, FirebaseUI does not provide local storage, will help you handle automatically all those method, `onChildAdded`, `onChildChanged()` and so on. If you want a local db, consider using SQLite.

Comment: Yeah, I am using ormlite for storage but facing an issue which I post.

Comment: It is hard to understand the problem without seeing the JSON that you're trying to read. Please update your question to include a minimal snippet of that JSON. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can't share json due to confidentiality issue. should I create dummy json so that you will able to understand? with Query I am fetching only new data from firebase db as I set `start value` but when old data modified `onChildChanged()` not called.

Comment: Yes, please create a dummy json to help us understand your problem @FaisalShaikh